# C# Linq - How would I apply filter in which way it could not compare itself

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am working on a project where I would like to update `Name` column of `Areas` table. While updating I wanted to validate if there is same `Areas.Name` available in database but while searching/comparing it should not compare with itself. I come up with below query which searches all values of database column `Areas.Name` but could not skip comparing itself.

```
    public bool IsDuplicateArea(string areaName)
    {
        return db.Areas.Where(a => a.Name == areaName).Any();
    }
```

Where `areaName` contains the name of area which I would like to update in database.

Any one have an idea how would I apply filter in which way it could not compare itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "it should not compare with itself"? It's very unclear what you mean here.

Comment: If suppose the value of `areaName` is Greenville and I am updating it with Downtown.... then it should compare the all values of column `Areas.Name` expect the Greenville. I hope its clear now!

Comment: why you do not make the Name column `Uniq`? and then you will not be able to add same name twice

Comment: @LucianBumb For a good user experience you may want to notify the user of a duplicate name as soon as the name is entered, prior to saving. A unique key is useful here, but only as an addition, not as a replacement for what the OP is doing now.

Comment: No it does not work for me. It results me the same as earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass the ID of the column and check it like follows

```
public bool IsDuplicateArea(string areaName, int Id)
{
    return db.Areas.Where(a => a.Name == areaName && a.Id != Id).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also only use `.Any()`:

```
return db.Areas.Any(a => a.Name == areaName && a.Id != Id);
```